# How can I force Excel to place Sigma Values pivot field into the Columns Label using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

In my Pivot Tables, I prefer to see the Value fields displayed as column labels next to the Row label fields. By default, Excel will create a field "Sigma Values" and move it into either the Row Labels or Column Labels. I would like to add to my Pivot Table Create macro, a line(s) of code to create and place this field into the Columns Label. Below I show the orientation I would like. Thanks in advance!
[The Sigma Values field is created by default. I would like to force excel to always place this field in Column Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCt1U.jpg)

Here is my VBA code, it is still not finished

```
Sub olderRTSPivot()

    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

    'point to top left of raw data table (ie the Exception Report )

     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name").Select
     Range("A1").Select

    'tell Excel to use this table to create the pivot

     Set objTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard

    'set Filter fields

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Aging Category")
     objField.Orientation = xlPageField

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Project")
     objField.Orientation = xlPageField

    'Set Row Fields

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Originator")
     objField.Orientation = xlRowField

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Created")
     objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    'Set Data Fields

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("RTS")
     objField.Orientation = xlDataField
     objField.Function = xlCount

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Days Aged")
     objField.Orientation = xlDataField
     objField.Function = xlAverage

     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Days Aged")
     objField.Orientation = xlDataField
     objField.Function = xlMax

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set DataOnRows property to False

```
pivotTable.DataOnRows = False
```